# Due to which reason might a windows 7 password been reset to empty?

Tags: passwords, windows

A user reports on monday he cannot access his windows 7 account anymore due to a "wrong password", which perfectly worked on friday. It turns out the password has been reset to empty for that account. Assuming that the user is not lying to the question whether he reset the password himself is there any other reason besides a hacking attempt on that user account due to which the password was reset?

If it was a hacking attempt from an amateur (an he didn't modify the log files) in which log file would the password reset been written?

Comment: is this a local account or on an Active Directory?

Comment: it's a local account

Comment: one more question: do you have any password policies in force that would normally prevent an empty password?  (just trying to work out whether this is user error or indeed something quite new and interesting)

Comment: I'm leaning towards user error, unless you have an enforced password policy. You could check the Security event log for the password change audit event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Local user password changes should register as audit events in the Windows event log, under Security. The event ID is [627: Change Password Attempt](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.0&EvtID=627&EvtSrc=Securitypedia/event.aspx?eventID=627) if the user changed the password himself, or [628: User Account Password Set](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.0&EvtID=628&EvtSrc=Security) if another user performed the change.

You can reach the log via:

> Start » Run... » `eventvwr.msc` » Windows Logs » Security

You can filter the log using the Filter Current Log button on the right panel, and enter 627 and 628 in the event ID filter list.

Comment: thanks. The log showed the user changed the pw last friday morning. After showing him the log he suddenly "remembered" changing the password on that day ;)

Comment: Never underestimate a user's ability to break things in stupid ways :)